# Is there a way to view previously viewed tutorials?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

A tutorial was shown when I first started  coming across FOES, which was nice and handy, but I can't seem to find anyway to locate the information again. I know that the colour around the FOE map icon is supposed to tell you how difficult it will be, but I can't remember the colours. I've tried locating the tutorial somewhere in my menu, but I'm not having any luck.

Is there a way to view previously viewed tutorials?

Comment: If the answer to this is "No", then I know what my next question is going to be.